# OS LDAP auth when LDAP server located in same machine

Tags: linux, ldap, db2

Is it normal to make LDAP authorization on Linux OS (CentOS 6.3) when LDAP server will run on same machine? I think I can't make authetication through LDAP when I start operating system, because my LDAP server will be still not loaded at boot time.

My purpose is to make authetication through LDAP on my DB2 database. And I read on IBM docs that I need to configure LDAP auth (or PAM..I don't understand differences, i'm newb) on opearating system first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine. LDAP isn't a complete replacement for local auth, but a supplement to it. Certain users, especially root, can always log in locally and are always present. LDAP auth allows a central resource for authentication for multiple systems, but there is nothing stopping it being used in a single system.

If the user that [db2](/questions/tagged/db2) runs under is a local user, it should be no problem at all. Especially if DB2 us only using LDAP to provide auth-support internal to DB2 itself.

If the user that [db2](/questions/tagged/db2) runs under is supposed to be an LDAP user, then the LDAP service needs to start before the DB2 one starts.

Comment: `If the user that db2 runs under is supposed to be an LDAP user, then the LDAP service needs to start before the DB2 one starts.` Here I can get an problem: LDAP server(TDS) uses DB2 database instance as data storage)